# How to install python-tk package without sudo?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I have an issue to install python-tk package for my app to user's computer. User does not have sudo rights, but has python installed by default.
I can't even find downloadable python-tk module to simply run "python setup.py install" .
Can someone help with this? Are there any other choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `python-tk` is actually a separately-packaged version of Tkinter, built straight from the Python source code; it's not a separately available source package.

What you can do is build and install your own version of Python in your homedir.

Comment: How can i specify path to python folder i want to use? I have one main python file for the app.

Comment: @Feanor: let the first line of the main file be `#!/usr/bin/env python`, then put the new Python installation's `bin` folder early in your `PATH`.